# What is the secondary market like for diamond jewelry?

Tags: commodities, jewelry

What is the secondary market like for diamond jewelry?  How does it compare to the secondary market for gold jewelry?  How do secondary market prices for pieces of diamond jewelry move relative to global market prices for diamonds? For example, if there were a physically backed diamond ETF, and the price went up, should I expect a proportional increase in the price of a piece of diamond jewelry in the secondary market?

Answer (score 3):

> For example, if there were a physically backed diamond ETF, and the
>   price went up, should I expect a proportional increase in the price of
>   a piece of diamond jewelry in the secondary market?

The other way around. If diamond jewelry prices on the secondary market go up - the ETF will go up. Gold prices don't go up because GLD is up, GLD is up because gold prices went up.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to imply that one caused the other. I mainly want to know how closely the prices will move together. Thanks.

Comment: @mushroom well,  you should check the policies of the specific ETF, but if its a trust holding physical assets (and not, say, futures or options), then you can expect the price of the ETF to track the market value of the assets pretty closely. Look at GLD or SLV for an example.

Comment: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/21677/investments-backed-by-physical-diamonds was a similar but not duplicate thread here.